# Using identifier in CREATE USER for the password

Tags: mysql, sql

a rather simple question, but I can't find anything in MySql docs saying I can't do this, apart from the fact the query returns an error.

I have a stored procedure for registering a user and it has two parameters for the username and password.

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD passphrase;
```

My problem is that passphrase is a unexpected identifier (as said by MySQL Workbench)
I was going to use ALTER USER, but I can't alter a table inside of a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build a string and then execute it on the procedure, that way I could build the pass phrase directly into the query.

```
SET @s = CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('CREATE USER ', @username), ' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \''), CONCAT(@passphrase, '\''));
PREPARE stmts FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmts;
```